# How do I get a new git branch to show its state relative to its remote?

Tags: git

Normally when I run `git status` on a `master` branch that has a corresponding remote I get info that gives me a comparison between my current branches state and its remote (at the last point communication occurred), e.g. something like

> your branch is X commits ahead of 'origin/master'

or

> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'

In a git repository I created a new branch

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

- added some new commits
- and pushed to to remote

Now if I add any new commits to my local repository on the `new_branch` and run `git status` it doesnt give me any information about how my local branch compares to its remote.
How can I get git to report this information automatically, like it does on master?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Comment: How are you pushing to the remote? What you ask is automatic for tracking branches

Comment: @AD7six pushing to remote with `git push origin new_branch`

Comment: That's why it doesn't work - see the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
git branch -u origin/branch_name
```

This will set up the branch `branch_name` to track remote branch `branch_name` from `origin`.

As per [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/):

> If you already have a local branch and want to set it to a remote
>   branch you just pulled down, or want to change the upstream branch
>   you’re tracking, you can use the `-u` or `--set-upstream-to` option to git
>   branch to explicitly set it at any time.

Comment: I have an existing branch locally, I tried your command - it failed with: *warning: refname 'origin/new_branch' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'origin/new_branch'.*

Comment: Try using `refs/remotes/origin/branch_name` instead of `origin/branch_name`.

Comment: Specifying the full refname of the branch you wish to track should remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

Your branch is not yet tracking an upstream branch. See [tracking branches](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html#Tracking-Branches). To resolve it, set the upstream branch once when you push.

```
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this would only work at the time I created the branch? as the branch exists Im wondering if I should use git branch -u origin new_branch` as per the linked answer

Comment: No, you can do it at any time. The only real difference is that `push` will push refs, while `branch -u` just sets the attribute. Both work.